# Defining the range of a regression in which the X and Y will change

Tags: excel, regression, data-analysis, vba

I need to create a simple regression with the Data Analysis Toolpack. The thing is, the range for Y and X input is always different. To illustrate what I'm trying to say, here's an example of the table I need to work on:

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
    1   Y   T   T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8  T9  T10
    2   19  1                                       
    3   13  2   19                                  
    4   14  3   13  19                              
    5   16  4   14  13  19                          
    6   17  5   16  14  13  19                      
    7   16  6   17  16  14  13  19                  
    8   20  7   16  17  16  14  13  19              
    9   10  8   20  16  17  16  14  13  19          
    10  20  9   10  20  16  17  16  14  13  19      
    11  11  10  20  10  20  16  17  16  14  13  19  
    12  11  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  16  14  13  19
    13  14  12  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  16  14  13
    14  15  13  14  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  16  14
    15  17  14  15  14  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  16
    16  10  15  17  15  14  11  11  20  10  20  16  17
    17  4   16  10  17  15  14  11  11  20  10  20  16
    18  15  17  4   10  17  15  14  11  11  20  10  20
    19  6   18  15  4   10  17  15  14  11  11  20  10
    20  10  19  6   15  4   10  17  15  14  11  11  20
    21  16  20  10  6   15  4   10  17  15  14  11  11
    22          16  10  6   15  4   10  17  15  14  11
    23              16  10  6   15  4   10  17  15  14
    24                  16  10  6   15  4   10  17  15
    25                      16  10  6   15  4   10  17
    26                          16  10  6   15  4   10
    27                              16  10  6   15  4
    28                                  16  10  6   15
    29                                      16  10  6
    30                                          16  10
    31                                              16
```

In this example, The Y input would be range A12:A21, that's because the first entry in the last column of the table (the "19" in cell L12) is in row 12 AND The last entry in the first column of the table (the "16" in cell A21) is in row 21; furthermore, The X input would be region B12:L21 for the same reasons.

After doing the first regression, I need to delete two columns out of the table and afterwards do ANOTHER regression. So if, for example I need to delete Columns J and L, the table would look like this:

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
    1   Y   T   T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T9  
    2   19  1                                       
    3   13  2   19                                  
    4   14  3   13  19                              
    5   16  4   14  13  19                          
    6   17  5   16  14  13  19                      
    7   16  6   17  16  14  13  19                  
    8   20  7   16  17  16  14  13  19              
    9   10  8   20  16  17  16  14  13  19          
    10  20  9   10  20  16  17  16  14  13      
    11  11  10  20  10  20  16  17  16  14  19  
    12  11  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  16  13  
    13  14  12  11  11  20  10  20  16  17  14  
    14  15  13  14  11  11  20  10  20  16  16  
    15  17  14  15  14  11  11  20  10  20  17  
    16  10  15  17  15  14  11  11  20  10  16  
    17  4   16  10  17  15  14  11  11  20  20  
    18  15  17  4   10  17  15  14  11  11  10  
    19  6   18  15  4   10  17  15  14  11  20  
    20  10  19  6   15  4   10  17  15  14  11  
    21  16  20  10  6   15  4   10  17  15  11  
    22          16  10  6   15  4   10  17  14  
    23              16  10  6   15  4   10  15  
    24                  16  10  6   15  4   17  
    25                      16  10  6   15  10  
    26                          16  10  6   4   
    27                              16  10  15  
    28                                  16  6   
    29                                      10  
    30                                      16
```

And now the regression would be with inputs Y (A11:A21) because the first entry in the last column of the table ("19" in cell J11) is in row 11 AND The last entry in the first column of the table ("16" in cell A21) is in row 21. Likewise the X input would be (B11:J21) for the same reasons.

I have tried in a hundred different ways, but no luck. This is the closest I've been to creating what I need, but I'm still lost since it won't execute the regression:

```
Sub Prueba1()
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select, _
    Range(Selection.Offset(, 1), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select, False, False, , Range("S1") _
    , False, False, False, False, , False
End Sub
```

Comment: So you are looking to run a regression, modify your data, then run a second regression and report both results?

Comment: Almost, I need it just to run the regression. The Data modification needs to be made by me because the columns I need to erase are not always the same, they are always changing, thats why I cant just create a code that simply states the ranges fixed to a region, the range needs to change according to what I stated in the Question.

Comment: It sounds as if you actually need a function that returns either a range or a range address that can be put into your original `Application.Run` as a parameter. How is the `Range("S1")` affected by the column deletions?

Comment: I just need to make the regression application's to have a dynamic range because the columns I delete won't always be the same. The Range("S1") is moved to the right every time I make a new regression, but I'm not bothered by it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This User Defined Function (aka UDF) will return the range into your `Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress"` as a parameter.

```
Function regress_range()
    Dim strAddr As String, c As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")   '<~~set this worksheet name!
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            Set regress_range = .Range(.Cells(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlDown).Row, 1), _
                         .Cells(Application.Match(1E+99, .Columns(1)), .Columns.Count))
        End With
    End With

End Function
```

You need to make sure that it is properly referencing the correct worksheet in the third line.

This would become part of the run command like,

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", regress_range(), False, False, , Range("S1") _
, False, False, False, False, , False
```

I'm still concerned how `Range("S1")` may change (i.e. shift right) if columns are deleted from the regression range. Additionally, it has no explicitly referenced parent worksheet.

Output starting at your original data block:

```
$A$12:$L$21
$A$11:$J$21
```

Comment: Im sorry if I  look naive, but how can I integrate that code into the Regression application code??

Comment: Hmm I think you're right... How could I make the output range '(Range("S1")' change to another range every time I make a new regression without it wiping the last regression data?  (BTW you're awesome for helping me, I can't describe how happy you're making me with your help)

Comment: If S1 (originally) is the last number, date or text going right along the first row (i.e. no number or date or the right of it, then `Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)` will capture it every time. That's like going to the extreme right of row 1 and tapping Ctrl+← so even if columns between A and S are deleted, it will always be the correct cell. The lack of an explicit parent worksheet still concerns me.

Comment: I was trying to make the code you wrote work but it always tells me there was an error: "Regression - Input X range must be a contiguos reference"
I dont know what im doing wrong :(

Comment: I genuinely don't know if it is a range.address or range it is expecting. It is supposed to be Range("$A$12:$A$21")

Comment: The function I wrote should be passing back a true range object reference. Consider passing over the workbook to the email address found [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=qna&forum=&filter=All&page=1&tm=1374165688591&auth=1#user-profile-tab-profile).

Comment: I just sent the workbook I have to do the work on. I cant believe how kind you are! Thank you!